# Use substrings of column names in across

Tags: r, gsub, across, mutate, r-glue

I have the following tibble:

```
df <- tibble(
  x = c(5, 5),
  Column_1 = c(0.5, 0.5),
  Column_2 = c(0.75, 0.75))
```

I would like to create two new columns, which are the product of column x and Column_1 and x and Column_2 respectively. These columns should be named ABC_1 and ABC_2.

I tried the following code:

```
df <- mutate(df,
  across(starts_with("Column_"),
              function(y) y * x,
              .names = paste0("ABC", gsub("Column_", "", "{.col}"))
        ))
```

However, this resulted in the following table:

| x | Column_1 | Column_2 | ABCColumn_1 | ABCColumn_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0.5 | 0.75 | 2.5 | 3.75 |
| 5 | 0.5 | 0.75 | 2.5 | 3.75 |

The resulting columns are now named ABCColumn_1 and ABCColumn_2. Somehow creating a substring with gsub did not work. My desired output is:

| x | Column_1 | Column_2 | ABC_1 | ABC_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0.5 | 0.75 | 2.5 | 3.75 |
| 5 | 0.5 | 0.75 | 2.5 | 3.75 |

Any ideas how I can elegantly solve this problem? In reality, the number of columns is variable, so I cannot hardcode 1 and 2 into my script.

EDIT: Sorry, my generic columns names were not well chosen. I chose a different one to show that the old and the new column names should not be related in any way except for the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glue strings used in the `.names` argument of `across()` evaluate calls so you could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Column"), ~ x * .x, .names = "ABC_{seq_along(.col)}"))

# A tibble: 2 × 5
      x Column_1 Column_2 ABC_1 ABC_2
  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     5      0.5     0.75   2.5  3.75
2     5      0.5     0.75   2.5  3.75
```

Or use `sub()` in the glue string:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Column"), ~ x * .x, .names = "{sub('Column', 'ABC', .col)}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    df <- mutate(df,
                 across(starts_with("Column_"),
                        function(y) y * x,
                        .names = paste0("New", gsub("Column_", "", "{.col}"))
                 ))
```